# disable absolute path in php errors

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, php.ini

Is there anyway to disable absolute path which appears with php errors.

i.e.

/domain.com/www/user/html/index.php on line 179

I don't want php to show "/domain.com/www/user/html". Only the file name should appear with line number.

Comment: Can you detail why? I don't think this is a good idea

Answer (score 2):

You could setup a custom error handler to format the messages the way you want. If it's a production box, you probably should not have display_errors on. Use the reporting log files instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Note also that if you have errors suppressed you still can view errors in the error log file (you can change the location of that file, too).

Comment: Yes, excellent point. Reporting errors and displaying errors are 2 separate directives.

Comment: I'd have given this +1 if you hadn't suggesting suppressing errors - only the (on-screen) reporting should be suppressed!

Comment: I did mean the display errors. I didn't mean turn off error reporting. I should have been more clear.